# Concatenate values from corresponding table

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, concatenation

I'm looking for a non-VBA approach for concatenating a list of of products from a corresponding table. If possible I would prefer to use an array-based formula.

For instance, you have a table of Customers and each Item they bought.

```
John    Apple
Steve   Orange
John    Pear
Steve   Grapes
John    Tomato
```

Then on a separate table I would like to list each person (one per line), and list the products they bought separated by a comma:

```
John    Apple, Pear, Tomato
Steve   Orange, Grapes
```

The closest thing I can find is [this guide](http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/use-index-lookup-multiple-values-list), which I can adapt to concatenate but you would need to know the amount of products they bought.

Comment: I don't really follow that example (read: I didn't really read it thoroughly or test it) but can't you use the `CountIf` function to determine "the amount of products they bought"?

Comment: the approach in the technique will work if you add a formula counting the amount of times each name appears etc... But the bigger question is to consider if going through the hassle of creating multiple helper tables and a slew of formulas is the best way to achieve your goal? You are trying to make Excel do something with formulas that it is not made for. If you do this on a regular basis, you may want to consider one of the open-source data analysis programs or Excel VBAs that are purpose-built for this kind of job.(VBA, Python, R, etc...)

Comment: Or VBA. A custom function could do this really easily.

Comment: Yes, David, thank you. just added

Answer (score 0):

I will delete this post as soon as you accept another person's non-vba solution.

If we start with:

[image]

and run this macro:

```
Sub ReOrganize()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, j As Long, st As String
    Dim M As Long
    Range("A:A").Copy Range("E1")
    Range("E:E").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    M = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        st = ""
        v1 = Cells(i, "E").Value
        For j = 1 To M
            v2 = Cells(j, "A").Value
            If v1 = v2 Then
                st = st & ", " & Cells(j, "B").Value
            End If
        Next j
        Cells(i, "F").Value = Mid(st, 2)
    Next i
End Sub
```

we will get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments it can be done with formulas, but VBA would really be ideal.  Limiting to only formulas adds quite a bit of complexity to it.

That said, I'm a sucker for an Excel-Only challenge.  See [example workbook here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10791482/SO_TableLookup.xlsx)

[image: Screenshot of working example]

Raw data is in Blue font, formulas in black. Helper tables have green headings.

- E5: `= COUNTIF(B$5:B5,B5)`.  Counts how many instances of Name have come before it in the table.
- F5: `=B5&"_"&E5`
- E14: `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$5:$C$9,MATCH($B14&"_"&E$13,$F$5:$F$9,0)),"")`. This looks up 'John_1' or similar from the helper table.  If no matches are found, it returns a blank string "".
- F14: Same as E14, with ", " appended to the output